не понимаю, почему не работает кнопка следующий товар в telebot, перепробовал все, ни в какую
    elif message.text == 'Платья':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        skip_prod = types.KeyboardButton('Следующий товар➡️')
        markup.add(skip_prod)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Платья', reply_markup=markup)
        photo = open('E:/AV_BOT/Фотографии товаров/sf.png', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo,caption='въахпъвахпъвапхваъпхваъпхвап')
        if message.text == 'Следующий товар➡️':
            product.prods(message) #это функция в другом файле, она как раз рабочая 


Паша из Франции вернется.. обязательно подскажет в чем дело) не знаток телебота, но предположу, что проблема у вас на сервере) отладка у вас же как-то происходит?

А как выдумаете, каким образом команда Следующий товар должна дойти до условия if?

elif message.text == 'Платья':
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    skip_prod = types.KeyboardButton('Следующий товар➡️')
    markup.add(skip_prod)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Платья', reply_markup=markup)
    photo = open('E:/AV_BOT/Фотографии товаров/sf.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo,caption='въахпъвахпъвапхваъпхваъпхвап')
elif message.text == 'Следующий товар➡️':
     product.prods(message)

Попробуй так, т.к. сначало message.text равен 'Платья'
Когда человек отправляет сообщение, бот отправляет ему сообщение с маркапом и бот не ждет следующего сообщения, он снова проверяет, но это 'Платья',
а не 'Следующий товар➡️', поэтому надо опустить на блок ниже, и все должно работать,
